# cannot access the internet inside virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have just installed virtualbox and set up ubuntu12.10 amd64 on it., I am using the same ubuntu on my host machine.

I am having trouble accessing the internet from inside the virtualbox. Could anyone give me any ideas as to why this may be / how to fix it?

Comment: solved: i needed to supply proxy settings

Answer (score 1):

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Check this post it might help you to configure.

Comment: I have looked at that before, and now again, but cant seem to even get the basic NAT configuration working, have tried PCnet-FAST and Intel PRO 1000 to no avail

Comment: @Calum, So what was your eventual fix? Which adapter you used?